# Magento2 install sample data after - I get invalid credentials

Tags: magento2, composer

I run `composer update` from root and I get:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
    Authentication required (repo.magento.com):
```

I enter my credentials that I use to login here:
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer/account/

and the same ones that I used to install magento in the first place, but I get this error:

```
 [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                     
  Invalid credentials for 'https://repo.magento.com/packages.json', aborting.
```

What sort of credentials do I need to input? Thanks!

Comment: The answers given so far are half answers. What needs to be done with the secure key once it is generated?

Comment: @AlexP how would my question be duplicate of a question asked after mine? shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: That's fair, but those one has good answers, not sure if it is better to close that one. It is up to moderators to decide, which one should be marked as duplicate.

Comment: @AlexP yeah, probably better to close this one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [DevDocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html):

You get your credentials by logging in to Magento Connect with a user name and password, then going to My Account > Developers > Secure Keys. There, you can generate, regenerate, or delete your authentication tokens to use to:

Download the Magento software using Composer

Install, update, or upgrade third-party components; and upgrade the Magento software using the Component Manager and System Upgrade utilities.

Comment: But how to use it? Where to enter the secure key?

Comment: @Detzler you've to generate the keys (by following the above process). and then Use tokens of Public Key as `username` and Private key as `password`. It'll then ask to store the credentials, enter 'y' and it'll start updating. I've just tried this and its working.

Answer (score -2):

Please follow instructions posted [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html)

Comment: Thank you for contributing. However, a link-only answer is not the best answer. Links tend to die so please copy the relevant section from the link as a quotation and cite your source. For more reading on why this is read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer then read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7519/157698

Comment: thanks, but remember what happened to the old magento forum and now there are thousands of 404s in this site.